# Could not resolve any of the following components: [JsonGraphqlForm]

Tags: graphql, expo, graphql-mutation, bluebase

I'm working on an application where you can control your Ac, Lights, and Switches with this app. It builds on the expo framework but we create our own plugins in expo it's publically available. by using this you can create your own app in just a limited time period.

Here is the issue:

> Error: Could not resolve any of the following components: [JsonGraphqlForm].
>
> This error is located at:

> ```
> in JsonGraphqlForm (created by LoginForm)
> in LoginForm (created by LoginForm)
> in LoginForm (created by LoginForm)
> in LoginForm (created by LoginScreen)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by Blank)
> in Blank (created by LoginScreen)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by LoginScreen)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by ScrollView)
> in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
> in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
> in ScrollView (created by KeyboardAwareScrollView)
> in KeyboardAwareScrollView (created by UserManagementMobileLayout)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by UserManagementMobileLayout)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View
> in SafeAreaView (created by SafeAreaView)
> in SafeAreaView (created by SafeAreaView)
> in SafeAreaView (created by UserManagementMobileLayout)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by UserManagementMobileLayout)
> in UserManagementMobileLayout (created by UserManagementMobileLayout)
> in UserManagementMobileLayout (created by UserManagementMobileLayout)
> in UserManagementMobileLayout (created by LoginScreen)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by ImageBackground)
> in ImageBackground (created by BlueBaseImageBackground)
> in BlueBaseImageBackground (created by BlueBaseImageBackground)
> in BlueBaseImageBackground (created by BlueBaseImageBackground)
> in BlueBaseImageBackground (created by LoginScreen)
> in LoginScreen (created by LoginScreen)
> in LoginScreen (created by Screen)
> in NavigationProvider (created by Screen)
> in Screen (created by SceneView)
> in StaticContainer
> in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
> in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by CardContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by CardContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View
> in CardSheet (created by Card)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
> in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
> in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by Card)
> in Card (created by CardContainer)
> in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by MaybeScreen)
> in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
> in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
> in CardStack
> in KeyboardManager (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
> in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
> in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
> in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
> in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
> in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
> in StackNavigator (created by Navigator)
> in Navigator (created by Navigator)
> in Unknown (created by SceneView)
> in StaticContainer
> in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
> in SceneView (created by SwitchNavigator)
> in SwitchNavigator (created by Navigator)
> in Navigator (created by Navigation)
> in EnsureSingleNavigator
> in BaseNavigationContainer
> in ThemeProvider
> in NavigationContainer (created by Navigation)
> in Navigation (created by Navigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by Portal.Host)
> in Portal.Host (created by Navigation)
> in Navigation (created by BlueBaseFilter)
> in BlueBaseFilter (created by BlueBaseContent)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by View)
> in View (created by BlueBaseContent)
> in BlueBaseContent (created by ThemedComponent)
> in ThemedComponent (created by AlertProvider)
> in AlertProvider (created by ActionSheetUniversalProvider)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (at ActionSheet/index.tsx:94)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (at ActionSheet/index.tsx:102)
> in ActionSheet (at ActionSheetProvider.tsx:35)
> in ActionSheetProvider (created by ActionSheetUniversalProvider)
> in ActionSheetUniversalProvider (created by ReactNativePaperProvider)
> in ThemeProvider (created by Provider)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by Portal.Host)
> in Portal.Host (created by Provider)
> in Provider (created by ReactNativePaperProvider)
> in ReactNativePaperProvider (created by BlueBaseContent)
> in ApolloProvider (created by BlueBaseContent)
> in BlueBaseContent (created by BlueBaseContent)
> in BlueBaseContent (created by BlueBaseApp)
> in IntlProvider (created by BlueBaseApp)
> in ThemeProvider (created by BlueBaseApp)
> in ErrorObserver (created by BlueBaseApp)
> in BlueBaseApp (created by App)
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer 
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException 
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
> ```

How to figure out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by adding `@bluebase/plugin-json-graphql-components` in `plugin.native.ts` file.

here is the code of that:

```
 import BlueBasePluginJsonSchemaComponents from '@bluebase/plugin-json-schema-components';
 import BlueBasePluginLauncher from '@bluebase/plugin-launcher';
 import BlueBasePluginReactNativePaper from '@bluebase/plugin-react-native-paper';
 import BlueBasePluginReactNavigation from '@bluebase/plugin-react-navigation';
 import BlueBasePluginResponsiveGrid from '@bluebase/plugin-responsive-grid';
 import BlueBasePluginSettingsApp from '@bluebase/plugin-settings-app';
 import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@bluebase/plugin-vector-icons';
 import MevrisClientPluginUI from '@mevris/client-plugin-ui';
 import BlueBaseClientPluginUI from "@blueeast/client-plugin-ui";
 import MevrisClientPluginUserManagement from '@mevris/client-plugin-user-management';
 import BluebasePluginApollo from '@bluebase/plugin-apollo';
 import BlueBaseRNPlaceholder from '@bluebase/plugin-rn-placeholder';
 import BlueBasePluginJsonGraphqlComponents from '@bluebase/plugin-json-graphql-components';
 import Plugin from './src';

 export const plugins = [
     BluebasePluginApollo,
     BlueBasePluginJsonSchemaComponents,
     BlueBasePluginLauncher,
     BlueBasePluginReactNativePaper,
     BlueBasePluginReactNavigation,
     BlueBasePluginResponsiveGrid,
     MaterialCommunityIcons,
     MevrisClientPluginUI,
     MevrisClientPluginUserManagement,
     BlueBaseRNPlaceholder,
     BlueBaseClientPluginUI,
     Plugin,
     BlueBasePluginJsonGraphqlComponents,
     BlueBasePluginSettingsApp,
 ];
```